# Separating a point and a polytope

Tags: convex-analysis

I would like to do the following:

Given the V-description of a convex polytope $P \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, a point $x$ which lies outside the polytope, and a point $y \in P$ which is the closest point to $x$ in $P$, construct a vector $v$ which satisfies

$$
v . p \geq 0 \quad \forall\; p \in P
$$ 
$$
v . x < 0
$$

In other words I'd like to construct a hyperplane separating $P$ and $x$. What is a computationally efficient way of doing this? The dimension $m$ is typically pretty large (around 100), and the number of vertices is also very large.

Comment: for simplicity, assume $x=0$. if you know $y$ then $\{z:\langle z,y-x\rangle=\frac{\|y-x\|}{2}\}$ is a separating plane. isn't it?

Comment: Well, yes it is. Should have thought about it before posting :) Thanks!